# Jquery to get the width between left viewport to a specific div on my page

Tags: jquery, width, viewport, stretch

I'm trying to get a panel that has a position of absolute on the left of my viewport to have a width that goes all the way to a specific div centered on my page, I need this div to have a dynamic width according to the viewport size considering my site is responsive.

here is a quick fiddle of my problem, there is no javascript since I am not sure how to go about this, thought you guys could help me out or point me in the right direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/jA3JU/3/

Using width:40% works fine for the start, but once you play around with the width of the viewport 40% becomes to small.

```
#square {
background-color:#000;
height:200px;
width:200px;
margin:auto;
}
#mask {
background-color:#000;
height:100%;
width:40%;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
}
```

I need the width of #mask to be the exact size from the left of the viewport to the left of #square.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need the CENTER div to have a dynamic width? or the left div to have a dynamic width?

Comment: the left div, sorry if i wasn't clear about that, the centered div has a fixed width

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery below, you can just make 3 divs that are contained in one and use all of them as display:table and display:table-cell.  It would do the same and you don't have to write a separate script for it.  If you want more on this, I will submit an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the fiddle doesn't like my `window.outerWidth` line, but something like.

```
var sizingMaskDiv = function () {
    var squareWidth = $('#square').width(),
        maskWidth = (window.outerWidth - squareWidth) / 2,
        finalWidth = maskWidth - squareWidth;

        $('#mask').css('width', finalWidth + "px");
}
// Sets initial width
sizingMaskDiv();

$(window).resize(function() {
 //on window resize, run function (can get slow)
 sizingMaskDiv();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jA3JU/17/

​

Comment: I played around with it a little and seems to work fine, but i think I need to adjust it so it resizes it on window resize

Comment: I actually wrapped it in a window.resize and it did the trick, but they mask only appears once you start resizing the browser window, how can i work around that

Comment: Just need to make sure you're calling that function initially. e.g. Dom ready or onLoad.

Comment: I have it all wrapper in a document.ready but for some reason its not working

Comment: I changed some variable names because they were bad, are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: that last update did the trick, thanks a ton! Is there a way to basically minus like 3px from the final width, it seems like its a tad to wide

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20974/discussion-between-maxim-siebert-and-christopher-marshall)